# Event date in post type

Tags: wordpress

In a post type made for events, how do I make the main page show the date I want the event to be and not the date the post was published

image of the post type

[image]

Comment: It depends on how the event data was saved. I suggest you check the postmeta table for that post id to see what the custom field key is for the event date. Does this make sense?